# Iterating over a nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with nested arrays consisting of 3 items, like this:

```
arr = [['first', 'second', 'third'],['one', 'two', 'three']];
$.each(arr, function (a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
 });
```

When I iterate over them with the above code, It console.logs:

```
0 Array [ "first", "second", "third" ] undefined  
1 Array [ "one", "two", "three" ] undefined
```

How do I get it to be log just:

```
'first', 'second', 'third'
'one', 'two', 'three'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `forEach` like this:

```
arr.forEach(function(subarr, index) {        // loop over the array arr
    subarr.forEach(function(e, subindex) {   // loop over the sub-arrays of the array arr
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

If you want to use `jQuery.each`, then use this:

```
$.each(arr, function(index, subarr) {        // loop over the array arr
    $.each(subarr, function(subindex, e) {   // loop over the sub-arrays of the array arr
       console.log(e);
    });
});
```

**Desired output:**

```js
var arr = [['first', 'second', 'third'],['one', 'two', 'three']];
arr.forEach(function(subarr, index) {
  var html = '<h1>' + subarr[0] + '</h1>';
  html +=     '<p>' + subarr[1] + '</p>';
  html +=  '<span>' + subarr[2] + '</span>';
  console.log(html);
  //div.append(html);
});
```

Comment: I need to perform an action every loop with the current 3 items, something like `div.append('<p>' + a + b + c + '</p>')`. How would I do this?

Comment: Yes the items of the subarrays

Comment: @Zorgan See the section **Desired output**!

Comment: What I intended was I need the items completely separate. My example was bad so I need something like `div.append('<h2>' + a + '</h2>' + '<p>' + b + '</p>' + '<span>' + c + '</span>' )`

Comment: @Zorgan Are you sure you only got three items in the subarrays, nothing more??

Comment: Thanks `subarr` was what I was looking for. `var arr = [['first', 'second', 'third'],['one', 'two', 'three']];
            arr.forEach(function(subarr, index) {
              var a = subarr[0];
              var b = subarr[1];
              var c = subarr[2];
            });`

Answer (score 1):

In `$.each()` first parameter is index and second is value so you want to `console.log` b

```js
arr = [
  ['first', 'second', 'third'],
  ['one', 'two', 'three']
];
$.each(arr, function(a, b, c) {
  console.log(b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to get each element from sub-arrays you need nested loop.

```js
arr = [['first', 'second', 'third'],['one', 'two', 'three']];

$.each(arr, function(a, b) {
  $.each(b, function(i, e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With ES6 you can also write this.

```js
var arr = [['first', 'second', 'third'],['one', 'two', 'three']];
[].concat(...arr).forEach(e => console.log(e))
```

You can create separate variable for each item in array using array destructuring like this.

```js
var arr = [['first', 'second', 'third'],['one', 'two', 'three']];
arr.forEach(function(e) {
  var [a, b, c] = e;
  $('body').append('<h2>' + a + '</h2>' + '<p>' + b + '</p>' + '<span>' + c + '</span>' ) 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to get the 1st, 2nd and 3rd item of the array separately

Comment: I need to make unique variable for each item (1st, 2nd and 3rd) so I can use them separately. Because I want to perform an action: `div.append('<h2>' + a + '</h2>' + '<p>' + b + '</p>' + '<span>' + c + '</span>' )` each iteration.

Comment: Thanks I've got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `join` method of the nested arrays:

```
arr = [['first', 'second', 'third'],['one', 'two', 'three']];
$.each(arr, function (i, a) {
    console.log(a.join(", "));
 });
```

Comment: Getting `TypeError: a.join is not a function`

Comment: `a` is a number as the first parametter to the callback of `each` is the index nut the element!

Answer (score 0):

function(a, b, c) => a for index, b for item, and c is nothing so undefined.

if you just want to iterate on array,

```
arr.forEach(function(item){
   console.log(item); // this will print inner arrays...
   // as in your case item is array, you can access their values using item[0], item [1]...
});
```

In javascript first argument is item and second is index, but in jQuery first argument is index, second is item.